# SQL query for getting message users in order of last message

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL query that selects the users from my users table that have sent a message to or received a message from my selected user (senderID or recipientID in my messages table).

The query is as follows:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE (ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(senderID) 
              FROM messages 
              WHERE recipientID = $userID) 
       OR ID IN (SELECT DISTINCT(recipientID) 
                 FROM messages 
                 WHERE senderID = $userID))
```

Given that the column `sentAt` is the timestamp of the message how can I order the return in order of which user sent the most recent message. I attempted to append the `ORDER BY sentAt DESC` to the subqueries but it did not return the expected result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Apologies, I edited the tags to reflect that is is mysql.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want a `join` instead of `in`:

```
select u.*
from users u join
     messages m
     on u.id in (m.senderid, m.recipientid)
where u.id = $userid
order by m.sentat desc
```

Comment: I was looking for a JOIN, your answer was a little off of what I needed as it only returned the user I was searching for messages related to but with some slight tweaks it worked perfectly. If anyone is interested my final code looked as follows:
`SELECT * FROM users AS u INNER JOIN messages AS m ON u.ID IN (m.senderID, m.recipientID) WHERE u.ID <> $userID GROUP BY u.ID ORDER BY m.sentAt DESC`